# Navigation change url, but not view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an angular application with a login component

this component is under `app/main/login`

I want to go to it from `app.component.html` via the button

Here is my `app-routing.module` code

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './main/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', children: [{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is how I try to use route `<button mat-raised-button class="btn-default" [routerLink]="['/main/login']">Log in</button>`

Here is `app.module.ts` code

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MainModule} from  './main/main.module'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MainModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is `main.module.ts`

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

When I click the button, the URL changing to `http://localhost:4200/main/login` but the view not changed.

How I can fix this?

Comment: is there a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your AppComponent?

Comment: Yes, I have it inside AppComponent @GérômeGrignon

Comment: please check this working example based on your example to see if there is a difference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmzh25?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems that you are trying to load component using *lazy-loading* technique.
So in **AppRoutingComponent.ts** file, instead of what your code replace it with :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', loadChildren: '(path to main module)/main.module#MainModule' },
];
```

In layman terms this just tells the parent routing module to load the main.module when main path is encountered

Now In **Main.module**, configure child routes as:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [
             BrowserModule, 
             RouterModule.forChild(routes) // Register routes for child module via forChild function instead of for Root
           ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class MainModule {}
```